# When accessing memory, whether is it slower or faster to access central memory access vs via non-local access (NUMA - interconnect NUMA)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, numa

Link: https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/solutions/sql-server-on-vmware-best-practices-guide.pdf

> This architecture having ultimate benefits also poses some trade-offs
> that needs to be considered and the most important of them—the time to
> access data in memory varies depending on local or remote placement of
> the corresponding memory cacheline to a CPU core executing the
> request, with remote access being up to X<sup>29</sup> times slower than local.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>29</sup> Depending on the implementation and the processor family, this difference could be up to 3X (Source: [pdf](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/Optimizing%20Application%20%20Performance%20in%20Large%20Multi-core%20Systems_0.pdf), p.6)

Here is an example (https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/understanding-non-uniform-memory-accessarchitectures-numa/) of the interconnect:

[image]

As per above quote - Time to access data in remote memory (via interconnect) is X times slower than local.

Had there been no NUMA, and the CPUs were to access memory (from central location), then will it be slower or faster compared to the interconnect access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As per above quote - Time to access data in remote memory (via interconnect) is 3 times slower than local.

It's saying, which should make sense, is that going further to retrieve memory that is not local to the socket, will take longer. I think that's fairly trivial for understanding but might just be me. If you have to go further, it'll take longer, like most things in life.

> Had there been no NUMA, and the CPUs were to access memory (from central location), then will it be slower or faster compared to the interconnect access?

In *best* case scenarios it'll be faster (no traffic on a single lane road, go as fast as you want). In worst case scenarios it could possibly be slower (traffic is backed up due to an accident on a single lane road, might be faster to go the "long" way around even though it's further).

The reason NUMA became a thing was because SMP didn't scale to having 10's of processors on the same memory bus. There was too much on the same channels and it caused gridlock. NUMA just takes SMP (I'm being really high level and glossing over much) and essentially cuts each socket to be SMP locally, with remote access to other memory (foreign) that isn't local.

Comment: Is there any limit to the memory capacity of 1 NUMA?

Comment: CPU and motherboard limits.